# How to move cursor in Mac OSX through Bluetooth LE?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, bluetooth

I am working on iOS app which is similar to Apple Magic Mouse, function of which is to mirror the gestures on the iOS device to the Mac after establishing connection between them using Bluetooth LE.
I've purchased a new HID bluetooth dongle and managed to set up connection using CoreBluetooth Framework for the last whole week.
However, completely no idea on what data of which format should be sent from the iOS device to reflect the gestures.
I've gone over the many tutorials and demos, but still no idea.
Please help me with the solution like the APIs or anything.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create iOS BLE HID service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827028/create-ios-ble-hid-service)

Comment: You could probably do this with a pair of applications - one on the Mac to receive the data from the iOS app and translate it into mouse events

Comment: thank you for your comment and apologize for not clear post. i've bought pealrsmart dongle and downloaded "Remote Wizard" from iPearl onto my iPod. And without running any application on my Mac, it exactly functions the way i want. I'm sure there must be some api or bluetooth services, but can't find it out.

Comment: And judging from being many apps like magic mouse, i'm also sure the reserve is just in the past and now it's possible to connect to HID peripherals from iOS.

Comment: It sounds like their app communicates with the dongle using the BLE GATT profile and the dongle converts it to HID events.  If they don't provide an API then you will need to try and reverse engineer their protocol

Comment: If it was possible for an iOS device to act directly as a HID device then you wouldn't need the dongle

Comment: as a matter of fact, i have kinda much experience in iOS programming but not in BLE. I'm looking the GATT profile through again.
And my iPod is actually working as HID, however, my Mac(hackintosh) didn't originally support bluetooth, i could not but use usb bluetooth adapter.

Comment: What do you mean your iPod is working as HID?  With a HID device like a keyboard or acting as a HID device to a computer?

Comment: acting as a HID device to a computer.
i tap, drag on my iPod, and the cursor acts the same on my Mac.
The ipod is real like wireless mouse.
thank u again for your comment

Comment: RemoteWizard.
would u install that app on your iOS device and check it out, plz?

Comment: It doesn't work because I don't have the required dongle.

Comment: what a pity! i've already done pairing, but don't know what data to send. however, it's likely to use the same api as the one general usb mice use. i've viewed your profile and am sure you could help me.
i need you and your colleagues' help.