# How to correctly construct A boot mouse BT HID Service record

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, hid, iobluetooth

I've being trying to build a simple HID mouse Service record based upon the example in the bluetooth document.

https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=246761

I've pieced together the majority of the plist but it's not 100% correct.
I understand the requirements from the BT hid doc but Im just having trouble fitting it into a plist file.

**For example**, if I try to set the

> kBluetoothSDPAttributeIdentifierHIDDeviceSubclass 0x0202

it gets misinterpreted as

> kBluetoothSDPAttributeDeviceIdentifierProductID 0x0202

**Another Example** is if I try to set

> kBluetoothSDPAttributeIdentifierHIDDescriptorList                 = 0x0206

My log files show a message saying

> attribute id : 0x0206 is reserved or undecoded

Here is the Service Record That I have created so far.
Id really appreciate it if somebody could explain to me what's wrong with it.

[HID Boot Mouse](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ge149uydgjgd419/HIDDictionary.plist?dl=0)

Comment: What platform are you trying to do this on?  iOS or OS X ?

Comment: I'm trying it on OS X using the IOBluetooth libraries

Comment: Ok.  I know that the HID over GATT service can't be published by iOS apps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827028/create-ios-ble-hid-service Your log indicates that there may be a similar limitation for OS X but I can't say for sure.

Comment: these guys here seem to have managed it [type2phhone](http://www.houdah.com/type2Phone/)

Comment: it turns out my plist is fine. It matches that of the app in the link above. My phone sees the mac as an input device but when I send a hid key press over the control channel the phone sends back a "not ready" handshake message