# How can I clone a non-paired BLE signal from a remote to trigger a device?

Tags: ios, arduino, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I have a projector that turns on via an RF remote.
I want to clone that specific power-on trigger via an arduino or rpi.

I have done some testing and it appears that the remote is a standard Bluetooth HID that works just as any Bluetooth paired input device for when the projector is on and its' onboard android boots.
However, when the projector is off there is obviously no paired BT connection. So I gathered that the power on button on the RC must send a separate RF signal. When I started to sniff the Bluetooth signals being sent by the remote via a BLE scanner app I noticed, that on pressing the power button it first sends a certain type of packet (which appears to be the standard BT signal) but then upon realizing that there is no paired device immediately (2 seconds) switches to another BLE packet. I'm assuming that *this* triggers the power on.

I have looked into non-paired BLE signals, advertisements, UUIDs, beacons but couldn't reproduce the same behavior on the projector (power-on) by using different iOS apps that sounded promising in being able to advertise UUIDs and by randomly plugging in what I could read out from the RC through the [Bluetooth Smart Scanner App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bluetooth-smart-scanner/id509978131):

- First reading

> ```
> {
> kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
> kCBAdvDataLocalName = "BLuetooth 4.0 RC";
> kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY = 129;
> kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY = 0;
> kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
>     "Human Interface Device"
> );
> kCBAdvDataTimestamp = "657062407.4927959";
> }
> ```

- Second reading:

  > {
  > kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
  > kCBAdvDataLocalName = "BLuetooth 4.0 RC";
  > kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <0d00ffff 42415634 2e3337>;
  > kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY = 129;
  > kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY = 0;
  > kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
  > "Human Interface Device"
  > );
  > kCBAdvDataTimestamp = "657078255.763785";
  > }

Can I prototype cloning/reproducing this signal with my iPhone or rpi4?
And if yes, which pieces of information do I need to advertise how?

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to achieve the same thing for Xgimi Halo projector. Have captured some of the data from the remote using the same app as you used and the data seems to be very similar. I'd love to be able to figure this out and  be able to issue a power on command from an ESP32

Answer (score 2):

Understand that the Human Interface Device (UID) Service is a standard Bluetooth LE GATT service.  It is commonly used to exchange data for a keyboard, mouse, game controller or a remote control.

Bluetooth LE GATT Services are more complex than Bluetooth LE advertisements -- **you can't just send a Bluetooth LE packet (e.g. a beacon advertisement) and expect that to trigger something in the HID service.**

One of the two BLE devices must establish a BLE connection.  Read/write operations to various GATT Characteristics are used to exchange data over this connection.  While the HID service has a [specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=245141) you can read to understand, the projector will most certainly have a proprietary way of using the HID service.  You will have to reverse engineer this.  The sniffer may help you here.

If you are only interested in the power-on operation, the reverse engineering process may not be that complicated.  It is likely that there is a single characteristic write that causes the power on.  You need to figure out which characteristic that is and what value should be written.

**Once you reverse engineer how the remote uses the HID service, you can most certainly implement it in iOS using CoreBluetooth APIs or on a Raspberry Pi using Linux BlueZ APIs.**

Answer (score 1):

**Important**: You may not be successful with the codes listed below since there's more and more reports from users that indicate that the codes could be device specific (what would make sense since otherwise all devices from your neighbours would turn on as well once you send the on command). Consequently you may have to look up your device specific code yourself. For this you can try [Bluetooth Smart Scanner](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bluetooth-smart-scanner/id509978131)  app for iOS. With [EFR Connect BLE Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siliconlabs.bledemo&hl=en) app for Android you can test the BLE command (see the instructions further below with two example screenshots). If you're using Home Assistant you may want to test the [Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant) integration from [manymuch](https://github.com/manymuch).

**How it worked for me:**

With the help of ubertooth I was able to scan the BLE advertisement of the XGIMI Elfin projector remote power on/off button. I'm now able to turn on the projector using

Advertising Data **XGIMI Elfin projector**:

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x12D7C7899B9F80FFFFFF3043524B544D`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

**Information provided by other users:**

For Elfin projector a second manufacturer data was [reported](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant/issues/26), thanks to [swampylee](https://github.com/swampylee):

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x38B4640F35F278FFFFFF3043524B544D`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

We now also know the parameters for **XGIMI Z6X projector**, thanks to [manymuch](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant/issues/5#issuecomment-1457447991):

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x12D7C7899B9F80FFFFFF3043524B544D`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

And for **XGIMI Horizon Pro 4K projector**, thanks to [uni-uni-77](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant/issues/5#issuecomment-1465380753):

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x1A7E0C743AEF18FFFFFF3043524B544D`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

And for **XGIMI H3 projector**, thanks to [netweaver1970](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant/issues/5#issuecomment-1482552849):

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0xD1497DBDA42360FFFFFF3043524B544D`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

And for **XGIMI H3S projector**, thanks to [mayongze](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant/issues/8#issuecomment-1524514427)

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x39BCA0F7A3ADB4FFFFFF3043524B544D`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

and/or (thanks to [Anbercube](https://github.com/Anbercube))

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x35548a967abddcffffff3043524b544d`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

And for **XGIMI H5 projector**, thanks to [rabdalov](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant/issues/5#issuecomment-1601377518)

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x4d4b17d86c27e0ffffff3043524b544d`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

And for **XGIMI H1S projector**, thanks to [FenixJun](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant/issues/18#issue-1773330323)

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x0ed8822f811cbcffffff3043524b544d`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

And for **XGIMI Z4Air projector**, thanks to [Hosiang1026](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant/issues/17#issue-1772754434)

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x0917B18FCB2222FFFFFF3043524b544D`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

And for **XGIMI Horizon projector**, thanks to [jack-webb](https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant/pull/24#issue-1840151051):

Flags: `GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]`
Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x33D731E3B22440FFFFFF3043524B544D`
Service UUID: `0x1812`

For **Xgimi Halo+** please see the post from Muxa below.

If you own an XGIMI projector you can test sending BLE advertisement using the EFR Connect BLE Mobile App (Silicon Laboratories). Hopefully the following screenshots showing the settings I used will help:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO5OD.jpg)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HLQs.jpg)

Most Xgimi advertising data has been compiled on GitHub on the Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant repository: https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant

Comment: What app have you used for testing? I've tried nRF Connect for iOS, but the UI looks very different to the screenshot you've posted, and I can't figure out how to create a virtual device with the same settings you've supplied.

Comment: Ok, I managed to emulate my Xgimi Halo+ remote using nRF Connect for Mobile on Android (it [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827028/create-ios-ble-hid-service) that HID emulation is now allowed on iOS. I had a nRF sniffer, so I looked at the packets (ADV_IND and SCAN_RSP) and used the values discovered to create an advertised in the nRF Connect app.

Comment: Congratulations, yes I tested with Android app. The iOS app looked different and I couldn't immediately figure out how to set up the advertising device. As you stated it seems to be because of iOS limitations. Did you use the same parameters to emulate (UUID and manufacturer data)? Is the manufacturer data different to this one for Elfin? 7E31DB31B22440FFFFFF3043524B544D . The first two digits (7E) aren't static while the others are. I don' t know yet why the advertising on the remote changes for the first two digits. It seems with every remote / projector connection they change.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your additional answer below. Please disregard what I commented before.

Comment: Additional remark (I'm commenting here because I don't have enough reputation points to comment on your answer directly): I once tried to turn on my XGIMI Elfin after it was off a couple of days and the attempt failed with the emulation. But when I used a non-paired original remote control (I had bought a second, identical Elfin remote control) the device turned on. So possibly the projector might change into a different status after being powered off longer time and I may have to investigate further if there's maybe also a scan response needed like you figured out.

Comment: Hi guys OP here! Just seeing that this got traction in the last few days -  love it. I've tried your solutions and they didn't work for me. Btw it seems I'm running the oldest of xgimi devices of you guys (xgimi h1). But@Helge your last comment may go exactly in the direction I mentioned in my original post (please reread). I believe that when the projector is off the power button is sending a different type of RF signal to trigger the power on. I also have a second remote that I was about to sacrifice to integrate the RF circuit on an Arduino. But I want to believe in a soft solution...

Comment: As I said - I feel like there is two different things happening with my remote when I press the power button and the XGIMI H1 is off. I captured what is logged in that moment:

01:59:35.46 Advertisement-->
UUID: ACBE715E-D953-1DF2-0403-E348617E6FF0
Conectable: true
Manufacturer Data: NO VALUE
Overflow Service UUIDs: NO VALUE
ServiceData: NO VALUE
Services: [Human Interface Device]
Solicited Service UUIDs: NO VALUE
Transmit Power Level: NO VALUE
Local Name: BLuetooth 4.0 RC
RSSI: -37
Adv Estimate: NO VALUE

Comment: I wasn’t successful in just trying to somehow send that UUID (legacy message too large according to the app). But I have a feeling it has something to do with the power on command. It is not the Manufacturer Data…

Comment: @kongolese indeed, I had read your initial post before I had ordered an ubertooth to see if I would be able to discover something useful :D I really had no clue about BLE before but now I've learned quite a bit. It was a great realisation that - as you had assumed before - the remote actually acts in two ways: 1. as a paired HID (classic) bluetooth device which e.g. simply sends key code 106 to the projector (same key code like Apple Mac Keyboard Power Button). But when there's no HID connection between the remote and the projector the remote sends those BLE advertising signals instead.

Comment: @kongolese I received a nRF52840 today and with nRF Connect for Desktop Bluetooth Low Energy App for MacOS I get manufacturer data like with ubertooth. The dongle is 20 € compared to 180 € for the ubertooth, so maybe you should give it a try with one of those specific sniffer devices. ubertooth seems to be to most advanced one but possibly nRF52840 is on par.

Comment: @kongolese just tested the Bluetooth Smart Scanner too and when I press the power on button of my non-paired XGIMI Elfin remote I get the manufacturer data shown for a second. It gives me all data that I used to emulate:

{
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = "XGIMI RC";
    kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <4600dd31 db31b224 40ffffff 3043524b 544d0d00 ffff4252 56312e30 30>;
    kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY = 1;
    kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY = 0;
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        "Human Interface Device"
    );
    kCBAdvDataTimestamp = "699150628.015071";
}

Comment: @kongolese In the second reading in your initial post you also have manufacturer data.This looks similar to the output which I get when I don't press the Power button on the remote: {
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = "XGIMI RC";
    kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <0d00ffff 42525631 2e3030>;
    kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY = 1;
    kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY = 0;
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        "Human Interface Device"
    );
    kCBAdvDataTimestamp = "699150611.145053";
} .Have you checked if there's a change in the RAW data view when you press the button?

Comment: @kongolese just an additional hint in case you haven't done this: When you test with the remote either make sure that the projector is off electricity or unpair the remote from the projector. Like this you can press the power button many times and the remote won't switch into HID connection when the projector powers on.

Comment: @Helge are you using homeassistant with the android tv integration? are you able to select source i.e. apps from homeassistant on the Xgimi Elfin? I have Elfin but not able to integrate it properly with homeassistant.

Comment: @Ahmed.B I have set up the android tv integration but I haven't really had a closer look. I think it showed me some of the source apps but not all that I have installed on my Elfin. Anyway you should better open a separate topic for this since this thread is all about the Bluetooth BLE commands to turn the projector on. Once it's turned on the whole communication runs via network and/or bluetooth HID communication which is a completely different technological environment. This could be also interesting for you: https://github.com/manymuch/Xgimi-4-Home-Assistant

Comment: @Ahmed.B manymuch provides an additional integration which works with UDP network based commands like Android TV integration. In addition he has integrated the BLE commands to power on XGIMI projectors.

Answer (score 0):

I also managed to turn on **Xgimi Halo+** projector from an Android phone and nRF Connect for Mobile app (HID emulation is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827028/create-ios-ble-hid-service) on iOS).

Apart from specifying the manufacturer data and the service, I also had to specify Scan Response Data.

Here's what I've used:

[image: Condiguration data in nRF Connect for Mobile]

**Advertising Data**:

- Flags: GeneralDiscoverable, [Device specific]
- Manufacturer data: `0×0046` `0x143FCB9335F278FFFFFF3043524B544D`
- Service UUID: `0x1812`

**Scan Response Data**:

- Manufacturer data: `0x000D` `OxFFFF425256312E3030`
- Complete Local Name: *anything (required)*

Thanks @Helge for pointing me in the right direction. After looking again at my nRF sniffer log for the remote (I used nRF52840 dongle), I've extract the data from the `ADV_IND` and `SCAN_RSP` messages and used the values discovered to create an advertised in the nRF Connect app.

Answer (score 0):

**XGIMI MOGO 2** manufacturer data is `0x23185B6ECE244CFFFFFF3043524B544D`, if anyone needs it.